# Google Play Game Services Unity: Mobile Restarted when update Leaderboard or Unlocking an Achievement

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am using Play Game Services for Android in Unity.

When I update my Leaderboard by following code

```
Social.ReportScore (20, "MY-LEADERBOARD-ID", (bool success) => {
if (success) {
msg = "Score posted.";
} else {
msg = "Score can't posted.";
}
});
```

This code is updating my scores successfully but after 4 or 5 seconds it restart my device. Same for Achivements.

I can successfully:
Login,
See Leaderboard
See Achivements

Error on:
Update on Leaderboard or Achivements.

Following is Exception:
**android.os.DeadObjectException**

I test it on:
Samsung Galaxy S3 mini
Q mobile A20

**Following is complete error Logs:**

```
04-24 23:54:22.981: I/Unity(13598):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/24/15 23:54:22 +05:00 DEBUG: ReportScore: score=24, board=CgkIqe-Sq_0PEAIQBg
04-24 23:54:22.981: I/Unity(13598):  
04-24 23:54:22.981: I/Unity(13598): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
04-24 23:54:22.991: D/dalvikvm(13598): Trying to load lib /data/data/gvl.zombie.test/lib/libgpg.so 0x424a19d0
04-24 23:54:22.991: D/dalvikvm(13598): Shared lib '/data/data/gvl.zombie.test/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x424a19d0
04-24 23:54:22.991: I/Unity(13598):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/24/15 23:54:22 +05:00 DEBUG: Native Submitting score: 24 for lb CgkIqe-Sq_0PEAIQBg
04-24 23:54:22.991: I/Unity(13598):  
04-24 23:54:22.991: I/Unity(13598): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
04-24 23:54:23.021: D/ChimeraSrvcProxy(2888): Creating service proxy ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.games.chimera.GamesAsyncServiceProxy}
04-24 23:54:23.021: D/ChimeraSrvcProxy(2888): Proxying container service ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.games.chimera.GamesAsyncServiceProxy} to Chimera service impl com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesAsyncService
04-24 23:54:23.021: D/ChimeraCfgMgr(2888): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.gms
04-24 23:54:23.021: I/Unity(13598):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/24/15 23:54:23 +05:00 DEBUG: Invoking user callback on game thread
04-24 23:54:23.021: I/Unity(13598):  
04-24 23:54:23.021: I/Unity(13598): (Filename: ./artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
04-24 23:54:23.101: D/dalvikvm(2027): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
04-24 23:54:23.332: D/dalvikvm(2027): GC_EXPLICIT freed 638K, 36% free 20493K/31687K, paused 7ms+18ms, total 228ms
04-24 23:54:23.482: D/dalvikvm(13749): GC_CONCURRENT freed 171K, 11% free 9612K/10759K, paused 14ms+5ms, total 54ms
04-24 23:54:23.482: D/dalvikvm(13749): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
04-24 23:54:23.622: D/dalvikvm(13749): GC_CONCURRENT freed 154K, 11% free 10008K/11143K, paused 14ms+19ms, total 75ms
04-24 23:54:23.622: D/dalvikvm(13749): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
04-24 23:54:23.642: W/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: unable to resolve static field 638 (PR_SET_DUMPABLE) in Landroid/system/OsConstants;
04-24 23:54:23.642: D/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x000b
04-24 23:54:23.652: I/MultiDex(13749): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
04-24 23:54:23.652: I/MultiDex(13749): install
04-24 23:54:23.652: I/MultiDex(13749): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk, false)
04-24 23:54:23.662: I/MultiDex(13749): loading existing secondary dex files
04-24 23:54:23.662: I/MultiDex(13749): load found 3 secondary dex files
04-24 23:54:23.672: I/MultiDex(13749): install done
04-24 23:54:23.702: I/ProviderInstaller(13749): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
04-24 23:54:23.752: D/GCM(2327): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
04-24 23:54:23.762: E/dalvikvm(13749): Could not find class 'android.media.MediaDrm', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.droidguard.o.a
04-24 23:54:23.762: W/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 181 (Landroid/media/MediaDrm;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/droidguard/o;
04-24 23:54:23.762: D/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x005b
04-24 23:54:23.762: E/dalvikvm(13749): Could not find class 'android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.droidguard.o.a
04-24 23:54:23.762: W/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 189 (Landroid/media/UnsupportedSchemeException;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/droidguard/o;
04-24 23:54:23.762: D/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x00a6
04-24 23:54:23.772: D/dalvikvm(13749): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0302 at 0x5f in Lcom/google/android/gms/droidguard/o;.a
04-24 23:54:23.832: E/dalvikvm(13749): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.hg.a
04-24 23:54:23.842: W/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 35 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/hg;
04-24 23:54:23.842: D/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0010
04-24 23:54:23.842: I/dalvikvm(13749): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.hg.a
04-24 23:54:23.842: W/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 449: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
04-24 23:54:23.842: D/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
04-24 23:54:23.852: I/dalvikvm(13749): DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/hg; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
04-24 23:54:23.852: W/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 32
04-24 23:54:23.852: D/dalvikvm(13749): VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0112
04-24 23:54:23.982: D/dalvikvm(13749): GC_CONCURRENT freed 339K, 12% free 10196K/11527K, paused 15ms+3ms, total 108ms
04-24 23:54:24.022: D/AuthorizationBluetoothService(2327): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
04-24 23:54:24.022: E/AuthorizationBluetoothService(2327): Proximity feature is not enabled.
04-24 23:54:24.082: V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(2888): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
04-24 23:54:24.142: D/dalvikvm(13749): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/681C2F668DCBE4CF20940E2F93EF45FBED1401FE/lib/libdD11BC7B78B49.so 0x424f4630
04-24 23:54:24.142: D/dalvikvm(13749): Added shared lib /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/681C2F668DCBE4CF20940E2F93EF45FBED1401FE/lib/libdD11BC7B78B49.so 0x424f4630
04-24 23:54:24.142: D/dalvikvm(13749): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/681C2F668DCBE4CF20940E2F93EF45FBED1401FE/lib/libdD11BC7B78B49.so 0x424f4630, skipping init
04-24 23:54:24.323: W/PowerManagerService(2027): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x1
04-24 23:54:24.353: E/(13749): statfs /mnt/.lfs failed, errno: 38
04-24 23:54:24.443: D/LocationInitializer(2888): Restart initialization of location
04-24 23:54:24.573: D/dalvikvm(13749): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'f.apk' (bootstrap=0) ---
04-24 23:54:24.703: D/dalvikvm(13764): DexOpt: load 6ms, verify+opt 24ms, 116652 bytes
04-24 23:54:24.713: D/dalvikvm(13749): DexOpt: --- END 'f.apk' (success) ---
04-24 23:54:24.713: D/dalvikvm(13749): DEX prep '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.apk': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 155ms
04-24 23:54:24.743: D/libEGL(13749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-24 23:54:24.753: D/libEGL(13749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-24 23:54:24.753: D/libEGL(13749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so

04-24 23:54:26.134: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:27.135: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:28.016: D/dalvikvm(13598): threadid=15: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
04-24 23:54:28.016: V/GamesNativeSDK(13598): Detaching from JVM on thread main_dispatch
04-24 23:54:32.160: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:32.400: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.android.widgetapp.programmonitorwidget (pid 13077) has died.
04-24 23:54:32.400: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.spp.push:RemoteDlcProcess (pid 13446) has died.
04-24 23:54:32.400: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.android.packageinstaller (pid 13465) has died.
04-24 23:54:33.161: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:33.552: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.android.service.cm (pid 13119) has died.
04-24 23:54:33.552: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.android.defcontainer (pid 13195) has died.
04-24 23:54:33.562: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.una2 (pid 13170) has died.
04-24 23:54:34.222: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.android.gallery3d (pid 12393) has died.
04-24 23:54:34.242: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process android.process.acore (pid 2458) has died.
04-24 23:54:34.252: I/ActivityManager(2027): Kill com.android.contacts (pid 2941): provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 in dying process android.process.acore
04-24 23:54:34.262: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2027): setHidden false
04-24 23:54:34.262: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.android.contacts (pid 2941) has died.
04-24 23:54:35.153: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:35.584: E/Watchdog(2027): !@Sync 133

04-24 23:54:36.154: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:37.165: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:37.676: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.android.musicfx (pid 13144) has died.
04-24 23:54:37.676: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.osp.app.signin (pid 13183) has died.
04-24 23:54:37.686: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 13553) has died.
04-24 23:54:38.236: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.pcw.device (pid 13157) has died.
04-24 23:54:38.236: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.gms.wearable (pid 13572) has died.
04-24 23:54:38.256: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.apps.plus (pid 10889) has died.
04-24 23:54:39.167: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:39.637: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process eu.chainfire.supersu (pid 13209) has died.
04-24 23:54:39.637: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.chaton (pid 13223) has died.
04-24 23:54:39.648: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.spp.push (pid 13275) has died.
04-24 23:54:40.178: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:40.408: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.thirdmoney.crack (pid 13377) has died.
04-24 23:54:40.418: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.spp.push:RemoteNotiProcess (pid 13293) has died.
04-24 23:54:40.428: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.gm (pid 13487) has died.
04-24 23:54:41.179: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:41.830: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.gms.ui (pid 13669) has died.
04-24 23:54:41.840: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.gms.unstable (pid 13749) has died.
04-24 23:54:41.840: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.android.vending (pid 13328) has died.
04-24 23:54:42.180: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:43.701: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search (pid 12473) has died.
04-24 23:54:43.711: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.gsf.login (pid 11729) has died.
04-24 23:54:43.721: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.android.app.clockpackage (pid 13643) has died.
04-24 23:54:44.102: V/AlarmManager(2027): waitForAlarm result :4
04-24 23:54:44.182: V/AlarmManager(2027): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
04-24 23:54:44.272: D/Launcher(2301): onTrimMemory. Level: 80
04-24 23:54:44.292: W/AlarmManager(2027): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-24 23:54:44.302: D/Launcher(2301): releaseShadows called
04-24 23:54:44.362: W/ManagedEGLContext(2301): doTerminate failed: EGL count is 2 but managed count is 1
04-24 23:54:44.452: I/ServiceManager(1674): service 'SYSSCOPE' died
04-24 23:54:44.452: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.vlingo.midas (pid 9695) has died.
04-24 23:54:44.452: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.wssyncmldm (pid 11066) has died.
04-24 23:54:44.452: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.android.app.sysscope (pid 11744) has died.
04-24 23:54:45.623: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.android.widgetapp.alarmclock (pid 11613) has died.
04-24 23:54:45.623: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.alarmclock.xtreme.free (pid 11024) has died.
04-24 23:54:45.633: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.android.exchange (pid 10125) has died.

04-24 23:54:52.971: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.android.MtpApplication (pid 10832) has died.
04-24 23:54:52.981: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.sec.android.inputmethod (pid 2236) has died.
04-24 23:54:52.981: D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(2027): updateLightsLocked() : Turn off notification light
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027): Session failed to close due to remote exception
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027): android.os.DeadObjectException
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:366)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:1447)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1459)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1479)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1102)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1116)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 23:54:53.051: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:1074)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027): Session failed to close due to remote exception
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027): android.os.DeadObjectException
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:366)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:1447)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1459)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1479)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1102)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1116)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:1074)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027): Session failed to close due to remote exception
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027): android.os.DeadObjectException
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:366)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSession(InputMethodManagerService.java:1447)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1463)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1479)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1102)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1116)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 23:54:53.061: W/InputMethodManagerService(2027):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:1074)
04-24 23:54:54.242: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2155): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
04-24 23:54:55.193: D/EnterpriseVpnPolicy(2027): Service has unexpectedly disconnected
04-24 23:54:55.193: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.android.server.vpn.enterprise:remote (pid 2609) has died.
04-24 23:54:55.223: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.process.gapps (pid 2327) has died.
04-24 23:54:55.233: I/ActivityManager(2027): Process com.google.android.gms (pid 2888) has died.
04-24 23:54:55.383: W/GamesClientImpl(13598): Failed to notify client disconnect.
```

Comment: Please don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It's generally a good idea to read tag descriptions before adding them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Dev Settings on your device, and make sure you don't have "Do not keep Activities", or anything like that checked.